# Linear algebra help!

Tags: linear-algebra

Find parametric equations for the line
$$x − 2y + 3z = 4, 2x + y − z = −2$$

I know that the first thing you do is cross the vectors perpendicular to the planes, but I'm having a little trouble finding the point of intersection - can I just set $x, y,$ or $z$ to $0$ and take it from there?

Comment: You need a point to form the equation of the line.

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble finding. Can I just pick an arbitrary point?

Comment: Of course, you can not.

Comment: Wrong question to ask - I'm sleep deprived right now as finals are around the corner. I guess what I was asking in the question was for these two equations, can I just set x, y, or z to 0, and then solving for the two unknowns? I'm terribly confused.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are looking for a point lying on the intersection of two planes which is our wanted line. Take $z=t$ into two equations, you get:

$$x-2y+3t=4, 2x+y-t=-2$$
Now eliminate the $y$ by every method you know:

$$5x+t=0$$

Do the same for $x$:

$$y=\frac{7}{5}t-2$$

So the points are as forms:
$$\left(\frac{t}{-5},\frac{7}{5}t-2,t\right)$$

Take for example $t=0$....

Comment: Oh man this helps so much.. thanks! I'm gonna do a couple more problems then head to bed, I'm sure I'm just too fatigued to figure things out right now

Answer (score 3):

Points on the line that is the intersection of the two planes will satisfy the system of linear equations
$$x-2y+3z=4\\2x+y-z=-2$$
which has as it's solution
$$x=-t/5\\
y=-2+7t/5\\
z=t$$
where $t$ is a parameter which maps out the intersection line as it varies over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are correct.